# 0xC0000005 error when open anything with sandboxie

Tags: windows-xp, crash, debug, sandboxie

> the application failed to initialize
>   properly oxc0000005 click on ok to
>   terminate the application

[image]

Any help would be most welcome.

Answer (score 1):

**[Finding a Solution for the 0xC0000005 Error](http://www.updatexp.com/0xC0000005.html)**

since the problem is related to the sandbox, i don't think we're dealing with faulty memory, DEP is more likely to be the culprit. add the switch **/NOEXECUTE=OPTIN** to your boot.ini

if this doesn't solve the issue, follow the instructionx in this **[MSKB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/188296)** to disable the postmortem debugger (Dr. Watson).

Comment: What should disabling Dr. Watson accomplish? By the time Dr. Watson is invoked, the program has already received an access violation exception.

Answer (score 0):

In Sandboxie go to CONFIGURE --> EDIT CONFIGURATION
A notepad window will open...
Go down to:

[DefaultBox]

Where it says..
AutoRecover=y

Change to...
AutoRecover=n

BINGO! I hope that works for ya'll as well